# Application.html.erb in rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails 4.0.2 .
I am working on a application with rails version 4 and ruby 2. In views the application.html.erb file is not working. It is not replicating on all the view files.

This is my code in application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Myapp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a controller named xyz_controller.rb  which has the following code:

```
class xyzController << ApplicationController



end
```

The application_controller.erb file has the following code:

```
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController

       def login

       end
end
```

The login.erb file contains the normal html code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the file in `app/views/layouts`?  Do you have any other layouts defined and specified in your controller?

Comment: Yes the file is present in app/views/layouts and i do not any other layouts present in the controller .

Comment: Please update your post with controller and view code and explain how you know the layout is not being used.

Comment: I have a controller named xyz_controller.rb  which has the following code :'class xyz << ApplicationController'

Comment: The first line should be `class XyzController < ApplicationController`.  And then your views for this controller would be in `app/views/xyz`.

Comment: @steveklein I have followed the correct path as you have mentioned

Comment: Can you update your original post with code from your controller and view which is not working?  Also, please explain there how you are certain it is not using the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your application controller should look like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Your XYZ controller should look like this:

```
class XyzController < ApplicationController
  def action
    #here you define instance variables used in your view for this action
  end
  ...
end
```

... so your `login` action, for instance, would be defined there.

Your view should be named action.html.erb, where action matches your controller action and that file should be in app/views/xyz.

The Rails mantra is convention over configuration.  This means that everything will be a lot easier if you (very closely) follow the Rails conventions for naming, etc.  I strongly recommend working your way through a good tutorial like [Hartl's](https://www.railstutorial.org/) if you haven't already.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please update your original post with your actual code.  What you show there now does not match my answer.

Comment: I have updated my code, I tried what you have suggested but my code is not working

Comment: @Priya - if you want our help, you will need to post code.  Plus explain in detail what is happening or what you are seeing and what you expect to see.